# Reproduce GroupBy statement using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I want to get the same result that this sql statement:

```
select c.CODE_LEVEL 
  from CODES c
 where c.CODE in 
        (Select CODE
           from AGGREGATION_CHILDS
          where PARENT_CODE = N'1')
group by c.CODE_LEVEL
```

with entity framework.

I'm using repository pattern, and I have tried this:

```
List<AGGREGATION_CHILDS> childrenCodeLevel = 
                m_AggChildRepo
                    .SearchFor(a => a.PARENT_CODE == aggregation.PARENT_CODE).GroupBy(a => a.Code.CODE_LEVEL).SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```

With this code I get a list of `AGGREGATION_CHILDS` and I only need `CODE_LEVEL` value.

`SearchFor` implementation:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
}
```

This is the sql tables creation statements:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODES]
(
    [CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_LEVEL] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CODES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CODE] ASC
    )
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AGGREGATION_CHILDS]
(
    [CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [PARENT_CODE] [nvarchar] (20) NOT NULL,
    [POSITION] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CODE] ASC
    ), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS_AGGREGATIONS] FOREIGN KEY ([PARENT_CODE]) REFERENCES [AGGREGATIONS]([CODE]) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS_CODES] FOREIGN KEY ([CODE]) REFERENCES [CODES]([CODE])
)
```

All records in `AGGREGATION_CHILDS` for the same `PARENT_CODE` will have the same `CODE_LEVEL`.

How can I reproduce that sql statement?

Comment: I think it may be clearer how to rewrite if you change the `SELECT c.CODE_LEVEL ... GROUP BY c.CODE_LEVEL` into a simple `SELECT DISTINCT c.CODE_LEVEL` without the group by.

Comment: "and I have tried this:" ... BUT ...? What exactly are you asking? What do you try to acieve? What does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using any aggregate the group by will just removed the duplicates, same as using `Distinct`.

```
var res = db.CODES.Where(x => 
              db.AGGREGATION_CHILDS.Any(y => y.PARENT_CODE == 1 && x.Code == y.Code))
          .Select(x => x.CODE_LEVEL)
          .Distinct();
```